# Why does a button and a keypress with same function work different?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, keypress

I want to achieve the same result in a keypress event for "enter" for something that already works for me on a button and somehow the keypress always duplicates the information based on the number of times "enter" was already pressed.
The first time it shows the information correctly and the 2nd time doubled, the 3rd time 3 times, etc...

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.dataa', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        save_data();
    }
});
```

and this is the function that works correctly if used on a button:

```
function save_data() {
    var final='';
    var datas='';
    var spans=$("body").find('#'+pruebaa).attr("data");
    $(".dataa").each(function() {       
        if(!!$(this).val()){
            datas+=$(this).val()+"-";
        }
    });
    final=spans+datas;
    $(".tabla").remove();
    dlg.remove();
    $("body").find('#'+pruebaa).attr("data",final);
}
```

The problem seems to be data's part since its the part that is doubled the 2nd time, tripled the 3rd, etc...

Comment: Where does this event handler is placed in your code ? You could try `.one()` instead of `.on()`

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the duplicity?

Comment: A fiddle would be most helpful as @user1717828 said. Also, an example of the data being used, or at least in the fiddle. Are you changing the value in the input each time, when you click the button and when you press "enter"? You're setting the "data" attribute to the "data" attribute + the value which might look doubled depending on what you're doing. Context, here, is everything.

Comment: I'm sorry i am not able to reproduce the example and the code is included with jsplumb and jqueryui and i dont know how to use fiddle with external resources working... I'll try to be a bit more clear, i want both codes to get values from an input or inputs and add those to an existing table. The table has values which in both cases Enter or button get loaded and the new data is added after. The problem is the Enter adds it as many times as Enter was pressed and the button does it correctly...